# How do I disable cells based on a previous input

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an advanced spreadsheet in excel that caters for people who really need to be told exactly what to do and what not to do.  So based on the selection in column A I want to disable some cells as follows (but only disable the cells on the same row):

```
Number- disable cells D, F, G
Link - disable cells E, F, G
Image - disable cells D, E
```

Any help much appreciated, I really am not to up on my excel/vba skills.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "disable" ?

Comment: By disable I mean that the user cannot type in the cell

Answer (score 2):

You can lock cells so they may not be selected.

```
Range("A2").Locked = True
```

However, this requires that you lock the sheet (with or without a password).

```
WorkSheets("Sheet1").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
WorkSheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
```

So you would just toggle which cells are locked as the user clicks on the 'main' cell.

In order to have this change when the user selects a new cell, you would need to hook into the Selection Change event (put the below code in your sheet module).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Target is the currently selected cell. So now you could test to see which cell is currently selected and then lock the other cells as needed.

With all of that said, I would recommend against this and instead use a UserForm.

**EDIT 2** - Updated based on comments.

Here's a simple implementation

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 1 Then
    Dim tRow As Integer
    tRow = Target.Row

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect

    Dim dLock, eLock, fLock, gLock As Boolean

    Range("D" & tRow & ":G" & tRow).Locked = False
    Select Case Range("b" & tRow).Value
      Case "Number"
        dLock = True
        fLock = True
        gLock = True
      Case "Link"
        eLock = True
        fLock = True
        gLock = True
      Case "Image"
        dLock = True
        eLock = True
    End Select

      Range("d" & tRow).Locked = dLock
      Range("e" & tRow).Locked = eLock
      Range("f" & tRow).Locked = fLock
      Range("g" & tRow).Locked = gLock


    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    Worksheets("Sheet1").EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  If you could be any more specific with the code supplied I would really appreciate it.  The above it like double dutch to me and not really sure what I need to take from it and if I need additional code.

Comment: I'll need a more explicit example of how you exactly want it to work. So if user selects A1, what needs to be locked?

Comment: When the user selects a value from a validation list in A1 the value in B1 is updated with either Link, Number or Image.  If B1 contains the text "Link" then I want to lock down cells E1, F1 and G1.  Similarly if the text is "Number" I want to lock down the cells D1 ,F1 and G1.  Finally if B1 contains text "Image" cells D1 and E1 should be locked down - hope this makes sense - thanks in advance

Comment: added simple implementation in answer

Comment: Other than right clicking on the sheet and clicking view code and pasting this in, do I need to lock the sheet first or anything?  Also, I should have said above that that code needs to work on all rows, not just A1 and B1 so is there something else that needs to be changed?

Comment: Updated the code. Unlock all cells at first and this code will lock them as needed.

Comment: I put this code into the spreadsheet but it doesn't quite work as expected.  When I select something from Cell A1 all other cells in the spreadsheet become locked apart from D1, E1, F1, G1

Comment: Did you unlock all of the cells first?